# If $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded in $\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, then $(Sf_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a convergent subsequence

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E =\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ equipped with the norm $ \| \cdot \|_{\infty}$, and $S:E \rightarrow E$ a function defined by

$$ (Su)(x) = \int_{0}^{x}u(t)dt \ \ , x \in [0,1],  \ \   \forall \  u \in E $$

Show that if $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence in $E$, then $(Sf_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a convergent subsequence in $E$.

So far, I've shown that $S$ is continuous, by showing that

$$\| Su \|_{\infty} \leq \| u \|_{\infty} \ \ \ \   \forall \  u \in E $$

I know that if $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence, then $(Sf_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded as well. 
But how can I prove that $(Sf_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Your family is equicontinuous (even equi-lipschitz), so you can use Arzelà-Ascoli to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

The result has to be true, because $S$ (the Volterra Operator) is compact. Here is an ad-hoc argument.

For each $n\in\mathbb N$, consider the partition $X_n=\big\{[\frac{k-1}n,\frac kn)\big\}_{k=1}^n$ and let $\{s_{n,1},\ldots,s_{n,n}\}$ be a partition of unity subordinate to $X_n$. Define operators $S_n$ by
$$
(S_nu)(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n }s_{n,k}(x)\int_{0}^{k/n}u(t)\,dt.
$$
If $x\in[(j-1)/n,j/n]$, then
\begin{align}
|(Su)(x)-(S_nu)(x)|
&=\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{n }s_{n,k}(x)\bigg[\int_0^x u(t)\,dt-\int_{0}^{k/n}u(t)\,dt\bigg]\bigg|\\[0.2cm]
&=\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{n }s_{n,k}(x)\bigg[\int_{(j-1)/n}^{x}u(t)\,dt\bigg]\bigg|\\[0.2cm]
&\leq\frac1n\,\|u\|_\infty\,\sum_{k=1}^ns_{n,k}(x)=\frac1n\,\|u\|_\infty.
\end{align}
Thus $\|Su-S_nu\|_\infty\leq\frac1n\,\|u\|_\infty$, which shows that $\|S_n-S\|\leq\frac1n$. Because the imagine of $S_n$ is finite-dimensional (it's spanned by $s_{n,1},\ldots,s_{n,k}$), the sequence $\{S_nf_k\}_k$ lives in a closed ball in a finite-dimensional space, and so it admits a convergent subsequence by the usual Heine-Borel Theorem.

Now look at the subsequence for $n=1$ and, remembering that it is Cauchy since it is convergent, choose $f_{n_1}$ such that all elements in the subsequence beyond $S_1f_{n_1}$ are at distance less than $1$ from each other. Then take this subsequence and put is under $S_2$, and from the convergent subsequence we get we choose $f_{n_2}$ such that all elements in the subsequence beyond $S_2f_{n_2}$ are at distance less that $1/2$ from each. Proceeding this way, we end up with a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ such that $\|S_m(f_{n_k}-f_{n_j})\|<\frac1m$ if $k,j\geq m$. Then, with $c$ such that $\|f_n\|\leq c$ for all $n$, for $k,j\geq m$
$$
\|Sf_{n_k}-Sf_{n_j}\|\leq \|(S-S_m)f_{n_k}\|+\|(S-S_m)f_{n_j}\|+\|S_m(f_{n_k}-f_{n_j})\|\leq \frac{2c+1}m.
$$
Hence $\{Sf_{n_k}\}$ is Cauchy and hence convergent since $E$ is complete.

Comment: Yes, that's true of most true statements.